# How to view jquery data() using Firefox/Firebug or other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I usually use firebug to troubleshoot JavaScript.

Other than inserting script like I did below, is there an easy way to view jQuery data() associated with an element using Firefox/Firebug?  I am open to other tools such as Chrome if necessary.

```
<div id='foo' data-bar='hello'></div>
...
$('#foo').data('bar','goodby');
...
console.log($('#foo').data('bar'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter JavaScript into most debugging consoles; if you type in your code and press enter you will see it's output beneath, like so:

[image: Google Chrome JavaScript Console]

The above example is from Chrome.

Comment: Thanks edcs.  Yes, I see how that works for Chrome. Know off hand if it is available for FireFox or FireBug?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see it now.  It is at the bottom for FireBug unlike Chrome which is in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Method I use is in Chrome. F12, Sources, put break point in your function, hover over the variable with your cursor to see what its passing/returning.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/BeginChromeDebug/view_watch.png

Comment: Never used this feature before, but I will investigate.  I see the JavaScript in the main HTML page, but not any external pages.